# Display different content on Mobile and Desktop

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to display different content (Mobile vs Desktop) via HTTPGET in an email using following HTML code:

```
<table width="579" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px;  padding-top:20px; line-height: 26px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; font-size:14px; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; Color: #4d4d4f;">
            <span class="deskhide">%%=TreatAsContentArea('VirtualCA1',httpget(@url))=%%</span>
            <span class="mobhide">%%=TreatAsContentArea('VirtualCA2',httpget(@urlmobile))=%%</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On Desktop it is displayed while on mobile it doesn't show anything. Any thoughts/suggestion on how to solve this?

Here is my code:

```
<head>
%%[
VAR @zipCodeLong, @zipCodeShort, @urldesktop, @urlmobile
SET @zipCodeLong = Lookup("Policy - Calculated","PrimaryZip","PolicyNumber",[PolicyNumber])
SET @zipCodeShort = Substring(@zipCodeLong,1,5)
SET @urldesktop = concat('http://yz.com/html.html?{**"ua_class":"desktop"**,"data":{"zip":"', @zipCodeShort,'"},"api_token":"1234"}')
SET @urlmobile = concat('http://yz.com/html.html?{**"ua_class":"mobile"**,"data":{"zip":"', @zipCodeShort,'"},"api_token":"1234"}')
]%%

<style type="text/css">

.deskhide {display: none!important;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px)  {
.mobhide {display: none!important;}
            }
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.mobhide {display: none!important;}
        }
</style>
</head>

Email Body

<table width="579" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth">
<tr >
<td style="padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px;  padding-top:20px; line-height: 26px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; font-size:14px; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; Color: #4d4d4f;" >
<span class="deskhide">%%=TreatAsContentArea('VirtualCA1',httpget(@urldesktop))=%%</span>
<span class="mobhide">%%=TreatAsContentArea('VirtualCA2',httpget(@urlmobile))=%%</span>
</td>


</tr>
       </table>
```

Comment: Anyone please?????

Comment: This could be an issue on either ampscript or CSS - would need the full code to be able to tell

Comment: My guess is that this is a CSS issue. Please can you provide a 'view as webpage' link so we can preview the rendered HTML email?

Comment: In an email or landing page?

Comment: @EliotHarper I have updated my code. Please can you look at it and suugest any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're doing this coding in an email, I would start by coding it minimally in order to determine the issue -- assuming that either **httpget()** could return nothing.

If this works, then you can add CSS hide/show classes.  If it fails, then the CSS is the issue.

```
%%[

/* @url and @urlmobile are set before this somewhere */

var @desktopContent, @mobileContent
set @desktopContent = httpget(@url)
set @mobileContent= httpget(@urlmobile)

if empty(@desktopContent) then 
  set @desktopContent = "no desktop content found"
endif

if empty(@mobileContent) then 
  set @mobileContent = "no mobile content found"
endif

]%%
<br>@desktopContent: %%=TreatAsContentArea('VirtualCA1', @desktopContent)=%%
<br>@mobileContent: %%=TreatAsContentArea('VirtualCA2', @mobileContent)=%%
```

Comment: I have manually checked HTTPGET function for both Mobile & Desktop is it's working perfectly fine. Server returning values either in Mobile or Desktop (it's not responsive), so I have to create two different HTTPGET functions for Mobile and Desktop. And then I have to hide one of them; like if email is render on desktop device then it should not show Mobile values.

Comment: How are you testing mobile vs desktop?

Comment: I am testing using Chrome's Mobile/RWD Tester extension. Also using SendPreview function of Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Comment: I just added a code in Original post. I was unable to post in Comments... :(

Comment: I have updated my code. Please can you look at it and suugest any solution?

Comment: I'd test the responsive with sends to real email clients, not in send preview or the Chrome tester.  Email CSS is so much more limited than desktop browser.  I'd take a look at something tried and true -- like a [**Litmus template**](https://litmus.com/community/templates) or something from [**Responsive Email Patterns**](http://responsiveemailpatterns.com/)